# C++ set how to sort a set by value and search by key

Tags: c++, set, a-star

I am implementing `A*` shortest path algorithm. The Openlist part stores all the nodes that will be visited. The list is like a priority queue that the first element has the minimum cost value and so in each iteration, we just pop up the first element and visit it. But inside the iteration, we need to loop over the neighbors of this node and check if the neighbor is in Openlist.

So that means this Openlist needs to support two types of operations:

1. automatic sorting
2. look up a node(by its ID)

The problem here is that Openlist will sort by the cost value, while look up need to be based on the ID of the neighbor node(the adjacent nodes). So I was considering using set, where the elements are the nodes. But I don't know how to look up an element by its ID in this set.

```
struct astar_node
{
    string id;
    double f;  //estimated cost;
    double g;  //distance from source to this node;
    double h;  //heuristic cost from this node to target;
};  

struct openlist_compare
{
    bool operator()(const astar_node &node1, const astar_node &node2 ){
           return node1.f < node2.f ;
    }
};

std::set<astar_node, openlist_compare> Openlist;
```

Comment: Keep two sets, one indexed by `f` and the other by `id`.

Comment: You don't look up an element by its ID in a set - at least, not without iterating through the entire set. That's not what sets are for.

Comment: @but what does find() method of set do?

Comment: @daydayup gives you an iterator to an element in the set?

Comment: should it be used as set.find(key)?

Comment: For example, if set s = {1,2,3,4}; s.find(3) will return the iterator; but how to search for an element(astar_node) here in my case? std::set<astar_node, openlist_compare> Openlist;

Comment: thank you both for offering the help!

Comment: @daydayup you have to search it. A set is only indexed on one value. `std:: find_if(OpenList.begin(), OpenList.end(), [wantId](const astar_node& node){ return node.id == wantId; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ containers, like `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::list`, and `std::vector`, and others, are "single purpose", or "primitive" containers. Each one has certain, unique properties that distinguish them from other containers; otherwise there would be no reason to have all these containers in the first place, of course.

The purpose of a `std::set` is to look up the values in the container by value, and to store only unique values in the set, that's it.

A `std::set`, like other associative containers, allow you to specify an optional comparator class that specifies, in effect, what the "value" means, for each actual value in the container. And you have done that, by, in effect, defining that only the `f` member of your `astar_node` class, matters for the purposes of defining what the set contains. All other values of all other members of `astar_node` are ignored.

Once that's done, this is it, as far as the `std::set` is concerned. The set can be looked up by `astar_node::f`, and that's it. This is the only way to find something in the set.

As I said in the beginning, `std::set`, and others, are "primitive" containers, and sometimes you will need something a little bit more sophisticated, as is the case here. In this situation, you can use several containers, and combine them in the manner to achieve the desired result. There is no law against using more than one container in order to store a single set of data. There is no law that says that you must use a single container to do everything that you need to do, with a particular collection of data.

Here, as I understand it, you also need to be able to find an `astar_node` in the set by the `id` value.

Fine:

```
typedef std::set<astar_node, openlist_compare> openlist_t;

openlist_t Openlist;

std::map<std::string, openlist_t::iterator> OpenList_by_id;
```

After you `insert()` a new `astar_node` into your `OpenList`, `insert()` returns an iterator for the new element in the `openlist_t`. You get the iterator for the inserted `astar_node`. Take this iterator, and put it into `OpenList_by_id`, with the key being the `id`.

Now, when you want to find something in `OpenList` given an `id`, use the map to find the iterator, then dereference it. Problem solved.

Additionally:

1. `remove`()ing an `astar_node` from the `std::set` will also require removing its iterator from the `OpenList_by_id` lookup map.
2. Since a `std::set` contains unique values, you need to handle the situation where an `astar_node` with the same `f` already exists in the set, and handle this situation appropriately.

Comment: thank you sir! ur the man. thank you everybody above for offering the help. and for 2, is the answer using a multiset? thank you.

Comment: Yes, a `std::multiset` would be the easiest way to go, provided that you do wish to support multiple values.